# Insert object in array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var x = [{id: string}];
```

I am trying `x.push({id: 'abc'});`

Its not functioning. Is Syntax correct?

Comment: If you can't get working, this does the same thing: `x[x.length] = {id: 'abc'};`

Comment: What you write is completely correct and should not give a syntax error, except that `string` will throw a reference error (But I guess this was just for illustrational purposes?). What is the exact error message? You might want to quote your identifiers though, because you have to watch out for reserved words if you use them unquoted. `x.push({'id' : 'abc'});`

Comment: it is functioning as per your code, if you want a null array declaration use `var x = []`

Comment: the syntax is perfect. You can test it like this: 
        var x = [{id: 'abc'}];
 alert(x[0].id);
Since x is an array that's why u need to access it by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Following line `string`  creating error because, I don't know why are you using this?

```
var x = [{id: string}];
```

try this

```
var x = [];
x.push({id: 'abc'});
```